# Deleted Google Play app by accident

Tags: google-play-store

My friend accidentally deleted his Google Play Store app. It is a Samsung phone. I don't know much about android because I use apple.

I clicked on settings --> app manager. It shows that Google Play Services is still running.

1. Does this mean the phone is jailbroken? How can someone delete a system app?
2. How can I get this app back?

Comment: please explain, how play store deleted? maybe he just removed app icon from home screen.

Comment: He doesn't speak English very well, but he says that he just deleted it. Assuming that he just removed the app icon, how can I get it back?

Comment: it will be there inside apps(app launcher), press on playstore and drag it to home screen.

Comment: The app is not there

Comment: You can download playstore apk from any below answers, and install it, that will solve this issue.

Comment: As Playstore is a system app, he cannot simply "have it deleted". Most likely, he just *disabled* it. Please check in *Settings › Apps* (or "App Manager", "Manage Apps", or whatever Samsung has named it) for Disabled apps. I bet Playstore is amongst those. Tap its entry, hit the "Enable" button, and it should be back. Please confirm.

Comment: The google play services are listed there but it only gives the option of disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all **not jailbroken** the word is used for Apple. for android, we use **Root**

The device is rooted I think. Otherwise, the system app cannot be deleted.

This google search will give you a lot of result. Download and install a playstore from it.

[google play store apk download](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=google%20play%20store%20apk%20download&*)

Comment: Agreed on "The device is rooted I think. Otherwise, the system app cannot be deleted." As OP would know if he rooted the device, I rather assume it's not rooted, and the app was simply *disabled* accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

The other day I did a hard reset on a htc that I didn't know was rooted I found out it most defiantly rooted when it booted up and it didn't have google play services no App Store. I basically did the same thing they are suggesting  for you to do  it works fine. I used a site called APKbucket I thought it was a little sketchy at first but it been safe so far and I've downloaded some pretty kickass apps. Good luck